# How can I checkout directly after I prefill carddetails in razorpay React Native?

Tags: react-native, razorpay

The options for checkout are below. Although I can get the items prefilled but still need to click the checkout button.

```
var options = {
description: 'Credits',
image: 'https://i.imgur.com/3g7nmJC.png',
currency: 'INR',
key: "rzp_test_J"
amount: Response.Amount,
name: 'X',
order_id: ResponseData.GatewayOrderId,
modal: {
handleback: 'false',
},

prefill: {
email: props.CustomerProfile.data.Email,
contact: props.CustomerProfile.data.Phone,
name: props.CustomerProfile.data.FirstName,
method: 'card',
'card[name]': 'Gaurav Kumar',
'card[number]': '4111111111111111',
'card[expiry]': '12/21',
'card[cvv]': '123',
},

};
```